# Fit videoview screen in framelayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout, android-video-player

VideoView is not occupying whole screen with framelayout. I tried it with relative layout its working fine. But I want it to occupy whole screen with framelayout.

Comment: did u find a solution? i have the same issue...

Comment: u need videoview to be placed inside framelayout alone?